# Does the set $\{\tan n, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ contain any integers?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Does the set $\{\tan n, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ contain any integers, and if so, how many and how can we determine these values?

Comment: Yes: $0$ for $n=0$. Only.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke How do we prove there are no other zeros?

Comment: $\pi$ is irrational and zeroes are only in $k\pi$..

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke There exist non-zero integers :).

Comment: Have a look a look at [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143263/how-to-show-tan-alpha-is-transcendental), which seems to rule out such integers besides zero by application of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: I think this should follow from the transcendentality of $e^i$, which is a consequence of Lindemann's theorem.

Comment: @ErickWong I know. That's why I only commented.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Ah, yes I just noticed the comment was only asking about existence of other zeros.